# No “Proceed Anyway” option on NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID in Chrome on MacOS

Tags: macos, google-chrome, ssl, localhost, macos-catalina

I try to get my local development in Chrome back running, but Chrome prevents that, with the message that the certificate is invalid. Even though it could not be the date of the certificate, as you can see in the screenshot of it:

[image]

I just wonder why there is no advanced > option to proceed anyway to see the website and being able to locally develop the app.

A few more things to mention:

- The local development runs on
  https://local.app.somecompany.com:4200/. It can't be just localhost,
  because otherwise our authentication http-only cookies won't work in
  Chrome.
- Therefore the host file under etc/hosts was adjusted to
  point to the localhost IP adress (127.0.0.1).
- The certificate was
  generated with openssl according to this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@rubenvermeulen/running-angular-cli-over-https-with-a-trusted-certificate-4a0d5f92747a) and this
  [repo](https://github.com/RubenVermeulen/generate-trusted-ssl-certificate)
- The certificate works for a colleague with the exact same
  Chrome version but with a MacOS version 10.14.6 (mine right now is
  MacOS 10.15.1)
- The chrome flag(chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost) does not change anything
- Also works in firefox on my laptop.

Can't find anything online that helped me to solve this so far, so I would be extremly thankful, if anyone has some more ideas what I could try!?

Specs:

- OS: MacOS 10.15.1
- Chrome: 78.0.3904.97

Comment: Since July 2020 the problem also occurs on Windows in Chromium-based browsers and Firefox.

Answer (score 1147):

FYI: Chrome on MacOS treats this different than Windows. MacOS version won't see the proceed button even you click `advanced` button.

To still proceed the visit as you are sure this page is safe, here is a easy way to do:

> There's a secret passphrase built into the error page.  Just make sure the page is selected (click anywhere on the screen), and just type `thisisunsafe`.

Ref: https://twitter.com/zairwolf/status/1196878125734486021

Comment: Thanks! it was useful. Do you know any way to make custom certificates as trusted for browser? adding to to keychain doesn't help.

Comment: Chrome 80.0.3987.87 just made this solution more annoying. It still works but every time my application is updated or the page is refreshed, the "unsafe" screen shows.

Comment: i normally get the procced link in chrome on mac but its not appearing today for some reason, this solution is fantastic thank  you for sharing

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for the "thisisunsafe" method.  That was a It really shows how broken security is on the web !

Comment: how do i revert this. it redirects me to a website i've never seen before. so im paranoid and i want to revert it. im on mac.

Comment: i would have suggested `google,thisisstupid_stahppit`  also, it's hilarious that they presume the local clock is wrong instead of the cert is "very expired", statistically speaking it makes sense, but really, if you can't trust the local clock in this case why would you be able to trust it if it's aligned to be within the certificate's window...

Comment: this also works for the v3.8x version of vivaldi.

Comment: Does not work on chrome _Version 91.0.4472.77 (Official Build) (x86_64)_ on macOS ;(

Comment: Wow. Thanks. This is insane. Worked fine on Version 92.0.4515.131 (Official Build) (x86_64) Mac

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks. Saved the day. I'm using MacOS BigSur 11.6 and Chrome Version 94.0.4606.71 (Official Build) (x86_64)

Comment: At time of writing, the cheat code (`BYPASS_SEQUENCE`) is encoded in base64 at https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/f8d4f3dec98d8a9836847c256753a12cd3e809ce/components/security_interstitials/core/browser/resources/interstitial_large.js#L19

Comment: For what it's worth, I have encountered this error on Mac and Windows.  I think the conditions for triggering this particular error may vary though, depending on the OS.

Comment: .... ok, BUT is there a way to bypass this without digit thisisunsafe every time I visit the site ? I tried to flag "alway trust" in the certificate but this is not sufficient.

Comment: This is an absolutely ridiculous issue. No mention of it in the error message at all. Good luck if you dont google the right thing. Thank you for this, but I'm still fuming at the fact that this exists.

Answer (score 277):

There is a hidden way to bypass that error, even if no button allows it. Of course, this should be used for your own sites only – where you are perfectly sure that site is not hacked, but simply local and therefore without a valid internet certificate.

Simply click anywhere on the denial page and type “thisisunsafe”.

Sounds crazy, but works to bypass chrome’s supervision of your safety. Chrome should get kicked for not accepting the certificate of devices in my local network. This is not IoT, this is "Ny Net"!

Comment: Duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/a/58957322/3657140

Comment: this did not work for me in Version 101.0.4951.67 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 121):

This solution worked for me.

- Right click, select inspect element
- click on console tab
- Copy paste `sendCommand(SecurityInterstitialCommandId.CMD_PROCEED)` press Enter

Boom! it should load the page :)

Comment: not working on my Chrome Version 89.0.4389.128 (Official Build) (x86_64)   :(

Comment: That really works for me - chrome version 92.0.4515.159. Thank you!

Comment: did not work for me in chrome Version 101.0.4951.67 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: this worked for me in Chrome 104.0.5112.79 (Official Build) (x86_64)

Comment: Works perfectly in Chrome for Windows 114.0.5735.134 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: chrome for windows v 105.0.5195.54 - didn't work, said "undefined". Dammit why does Google have to be THAT stupid? And "thisisunsafe" didn't work either.

Comment: works on edge too, this is still happening lol

Comment: The year 2024, Edge version 122.0.2365.80, hit F12 and paste. This is the one that still works.

Answer (score 26):

To make even macOS Chrome show the "Proceed" link under advanced, make sure to create the certificate with the *TLS Web Server Authentication* in the X509 extensions.

Here's a oneliner to create with that extension:

```
openssl req \
  -newkey rsa:2048 \
  -x509 \
  -new \
  -nodes \
  -keyout server.key \
  -out server.crt  \
  -subj /CN=test1   \
  -sha256  \
  -days 3650  \
  -addext "subjectAltName = DNS:foo.co.uk,IP:127.0.0.1,IP:192.168.1.1" \
  -addext "extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth"
```

If you MacOS *openssl* does not have  `addext` option, then use this alternate form:

```
openssl req \
  -newkey rsa:2048 \
  -x509 \
  -nodes \
  -keyout server.key \
  -new \
  -out server.crt \
  -subj /CN=test1 \
  -extensions v3_new \
  -config <(cat /System/Library/OpenSSL/openssl.cnf \
  <(printf '[v3_new]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:a.spectrocloud.com\nextendedKeyUsage=serverAuth')) \
  -sha256 \
  -days 3650
```

The key being `extendedKeyUsage=serverAuth`.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for - adding the `serverAuth` EKU.  Thanks.

Comment: I have to drop the `-extensions v3_new` for it to work in MacOS. Thanks

Answer (score 16):

Click on advance and then Click on the Page (not the address bar) and type --> "thisisunsafe" (without the double quotes) and press enter, you will not see what you typed but believe me it will work :) and you will be able to access the URL.

Comment: Thank you.  I have not felt this cool since I ordered my first In-N-Out burger "animal style".

Comment: what black magic is this?

Comment: OMG I did not believe this was true but I tried anyway. I clicked anywhere in the page, typed "thisisunsafe" and pressed enter. It worked! Thank you so much

Answer (score 12):

in MacOS Catalina I had it working by:

1. copy pasting the PEM certificate content into a text editor (such as vi) and saving it as a .pem file (*e.g. localhost.pem*)
2. in finder, open the cert file you've just created and add it to the System Keychain
3. a **Keychain Access** window will be show; open your localhost cert
4. set "Always Trust" for **Secure Sockets Layer (SSL**) as depicted below

[image]

That's it, refresh your browser and it should work just fine :)

Answer (score 11):

After a long search, I have found a solution. This solution is for mac.

1. First, got to **settings**.
2. Search for **manage certificates**. **KeychainAccess** will open.
3. Try to find the name of the certificate, for example localhost was the name in my case. If you click on the certificate it will show the details.
4. Then the **Trust** section you have to select **Always Trust** for "when using this certificate".
5. Now check in the browser again. You will directly be able to access the page. Privacy error, Your connection is not private message will not come.

Answer (score 9):

**Make a browser trust an SSL certificate**

In Chrome, we can write the following URL in the search bar: chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost and activate the relative option.

courtesy:https://www.thomasvitale.com/https-spring-boot-ssl-certificate/

Comment: by far the best answer... even not so highly rated, if you're a developer, you don't want to type each time the magic sentence. 'thisisunsafe'

Answer (score 4):

This error can be simply bypassed by starting the chrome in insecure mode as follows.

```
google-chrome --args --disable-web-security --allow-running-insecure-content --user-data-dir=/tmp/chrome-insecure/ -ignore-certificate-errors
```

Answer (score 2):

So after adding this question a colleague found this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1492207/neterr-cert-revoked-in-chrome-chromium-introduced-with-macos-catalina).

There seem to be two options to solve this issue:

- Just install the certificate in MacOS key chain. Then double click on it and under "trust" select "always trust".
- Generate a certificate according to the new [MacOS Catalina specs](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210176).

Answer (score 2):

Just click on "Not Secure" on search bar of chrome denial page , then click certificate, then you can see your certificate. click on Trust option do always trust.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to launch Chrome with parameter "--ignore-certificate-errors".

Steps for Mac OS:

- Close Chrome.
- From the Finder, select “Go” > “Utilities“.
- Launch “Terminal“.
- Type the following command, then press “Enter“:

  /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --ignore-certificate-errors &> /dev/null &

Solution from https://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-bypass-your-connection-is-not-private-message

Comment: This solves the problem, but always keep in mind that this solution changes chrom completely: Never open another tab to another internet site, as that will ignore certificate errors as well. It's a pitty that Chrome can not easily be told to accept site-specific certificate errors, as this is my PC, my Chrome and my IoT-device without any cloud.

Comment: Not supported on _macOS_ ??

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with same issue on multiple browsers. After banging my head around, I looked for any invalid certificate(s) or entries having red cross icon underneath, and deleted them. Afterwards, I never came across that error screen saying **'You connection is not private'**

If you are on **Mac**, follow steps below:

- Open **Keychain Access**
- Select **System Roots** from left bar
- Navigate to **Certificates** Tab
- Locate any invalid certificate with red cross icon, Right click and hit **Delete**

And also follow:

- Select **System** from left bar
- Navigate to **All Items** and **Passwords** Tab(s)
- Locate any invalid entry with red cross icon, Right click and hit **Delete**

Now refresh and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

FOR WINDOWS USERS RUNNING Self-Signed Certs on LOCALHOST

- Navigate to the folder that contains your [name].crt file
- Double-click the .crt file
- Click "Install Certificate"
- Select which location you want and click next
- Select "Place all certificates in the following store" then click browser
- Select "Trusted Root Certificate Authorities" as the location then
  click next
- Then click finish

Backtrack to your localhost site and refresh the page. Make the API call with crossed fingers and the ERROR should go away.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me in 2021 on my 2007 iMac:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3FgAztrYYo

Letsencrypt root certificate link is included.