# How to skip or disable SSL check for browsers in mac os?

Tags: macos, ssl

When we try to access SSL secured URL(or site) for development purpose or some other need it shows following error when browser doesn't find the valid SSL certificate for that particular site which we are accessing.

[image]

In WINDOWS OS it displays PROCEED option but in MAC OS it doesn't display this option.

So how to simply skip this SSL check for browsers in MAC OS or in other Operating Systems.

Comment: You can go through the following link to skip SSL check in **chrome** browser for **MAC OS**
https://medium.com/@dblazeski/chrome-bypass-net-err-cert-invalid-for-development-daefae43eb12

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No “Proceed Anyway” option on NET::ERR\_CERT\_INVALID in Chrome on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58802767/no-proceed-anyway-option-on-neterr-cert-invalid-in-chrome-on-macos)

Answer (score 0):

As the information explicitly say: the site uses HSTS. This means the site was visited before and the browser cached the information that the site requests access by HTTPS only and does allow to skip certificate warnings. Thus there is explicitly no simple way around it - by design of HSTS. This is not specific to MacOS.

To work around this you need to make sure that the browser no longer remembers the site as using HSTS. How to do this depends on the specific browser (and not the OS). See [here](https://www.ssl2buy.com/wiki/how-to-clear-hsts-settings-on-chrome-firefox-and-ie-browsers) for some instructions, including instructions for Chrome which you seem to use.

Comment: In MAC OS chrome doesn't displays the PROCEED button, so just simply want to access https based url.

Comment: @ZiaullhaqSavanur: Again, the site uses HSTS. In this case no proceed button will be displayed. This is not specific to MacOS but is specific to the site.It will be possible to skip other warnings on other sites which don't use HSTS with Chrome on MacOS. It will also not be possible to skip the warning on other OS with Chrome, at least as long the site was visited before so that the browser knows about HSTS. That's a feature of HSTS.