# NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID error at every page

Tags: google-chrome, browser, connection, private

I get the NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID message for every single site. On the screenshot I'm at support.google.com, and it still says the connection is invalid.

I have tried typing the `thisisunsafe` code, but it only unlocks the current page, and whenever I go to another it gives the same error message.

Also, other browsers, like Safari or Brave works perfectly at the same time. (firefox gives the same message tho)

[image]

Comment: Solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58802767/no-proceed-anyway-option-on-neterr-cert-invalid-in-chrome-on-macos

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me and what fixed it was turing off Avast One Web Shield.
I suggest turning off all VPNs and web antivirus and checking if pages that were previously problematic start working again. If they do then you have pin pointed the problem. Otherwise it is worth checking your chrome version is up to date.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33024998)

Answer (score 0):

For me, this issue got resolved just after updating the chrome browser.
Open chrome browser → Help → Click on "About Chrome browser".
It will check for the update and will update the browser to its latest version.

[Version which solved the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5k6fs.png)